# Lenovo Yoga 900 Switch Function (FN) Keys

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I'm buying a Lenovo Yoga 900, and I'm wondering if you can switch its keyboard's function keys.  Right now they are set that you have to press FN + F6 to press F6.

My friend has a Lenovo Yoga 3 and it has the same type of keyboard.  We tried switching it in the bios, but it turns out the escape key also has a function (reading mode or something).  So when you switch it, the function keys (F5, F6, ect...) work, but now you have to press FN + ESC to press escape...

This won't work for me and I was wondering if it is the same in the Yoga 900.  If so, is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I bought it, and I found that I can just switch it in the bios and it doesn't do anything to the escape key!  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed using `Keyboard properties` in many models. Take a look at [Is it possible to use F5 key without pressing Fn on Thinkpad E530](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/Is-it-possible-to-use-F5-key-without-pressing-Fn-on-Thinkpad/ta-p/899207)

[image]

Comment: It does not have this on the Yoga 900.